# Oracle12c - Can't create a table with partitioning "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a table with partitions but, I constantly get the same error. The exact oracle version is 12.1.0.2.0

```
create table toys (
  name varchar2(10),
  weight number,
  color varchar2(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
partition by list (color) partitions (
  partition p_green values ('green'),
  partition p_red values ('red')
);
```

Is there some other prerequisite that must be done before I can created a partitioned table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VALUES keyword is required:

```
create table toys (
  name varchar2(10),
  weight number,
  color varchar2(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
partition by list (color) -- partitions  -- removed
                          -- automatic
(
  partition p_green VALUES('green'),
  partition p_red VALUES('red')
  --,partition p_def VALUES(DEFAULT)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0c7b0eb21822fd51b61b178c46042ac)**

Comment: Awesome thank you. I actually already had the values keyword I just forget it in this post but, it was removing the "partitions" keyword that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Also qq, do you recommend if I use a DEFAULT partition for colors that aren't green or red ? or what would happen if I tried inserting data to the table that didn't fall under either partition ?

Comment: @user3696953 If you are expecting other values than green/red then you could use either default PARTITION or AUTOMATIC could be used: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0c7b0eb21822fd51b61b178c46042ac